# Generalise ways to choose a given amount from 2 sources

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose there are two bags  with 10 balls and 20 balls respectively.If it is always necessary to select at least one ball from each bag.
Then,
total number of ways to select 3 balls out of these will be :

```
C(1,10)* C(2,20) + C(2,10)*C(1,20)
```

Similarly if we need to take total of k balls: where `k <= min(10,20)` ie min(balls in bag 1, balls in bag 2).

This will be:

```
C(1,10)*C(k-1,20) + C(2,10)*C(k-2,20)+......+C(k-1,10)*C(1,20)
```

Can this be generalised to a easy and less time consuming relation for a given `k`,`n1` and `n2` where `n1` and `n2` are balls in bag 1 and bag 2 respectively.

Note: Only two bags are present in all cases.

Comment: You may find it easier to count the number of ways of selecting $k$ balls from a single bag at a time rather than both.  If we were to have combined the bags, there are $\binom{30}{k}$ ways to select the $k$ balls.  The "bad ways" in which this could have occurred is if all $k$ came from the first bag, or all $k$ came from the second bag which can occur in ____ number of ways.  Subtracting the number of "bad ways" this could occur from our earlier count leaves only the count of the number of "good ways" in which it can happen.

Comment: Related: [vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity)

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks never thought like that :)

Comment: As one more aside, the notation $\binom{n}{k}$ to denote the [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) the number of ways of selecting a subset of size $k$ from a set of size $n$ is the most common.  In decreasing order of prevalence in my experience is $C(n,k), ~_nC_k, C_{n,k}$ and $~^nC_k$.  I almost never see $C(k,n)$ and I expect that you will confuse yourself reading other works and pages which use the opposite $C(n,k)$ notation if you continue to use the notation you are.  Match whatever notation your teacher uses for now, but be aware of the more common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove this from unanswered queue:

As per [vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity) we have

$$\color{red}{\binom{n_1}{0}\binom{n_2}{k}}+\binom{n_1}{1}\binom{n_2}{k-1}+\binom{n_1}{2}\binom{n_2}{k-2}+\dots+\binom{n_1}{k-1}\binom{n_2}{1}+\color{red}{\binom{n_1}{k}\binom{n_2}{0}}\\=\binom{n_1+n_2}{k}$$

so by subtracting, we get:

$$\binom{n_1}{1}\binom{n_2}{k-1}+\binom{n_1}{2}\binom{n_2}{k-2}+\dots+\binom{n_1}{k-1}\binom{n_2}{1}\\=\binom{n_1+n_2}{k}-\binom{n_2}{k}-\binom{n_1}{k}$$

---

Alternatively phrased, combine the bags and count how many ways you can select $k$ balls from the combined bag.  Remove from your count the number of ways the balls all came from the same original bag.

---

Note also: the above identity does not require that $0\leq k\leq \min(n_1,n_2)$